# Write a .bat file with %xxx% content from another .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I want to use my batch file, which I converted to an exe file, to create another batch file that has the content `%key%` in it.

When I try to execute the `.exe` file, the `%key%` is ignored/deleted.

The same thing happens when using `%random%`.

How can I prevent my 1st batch file, with which I create the 2nd one, from deleting `%xxx%` expressions?

I want the the 1st batch to just ignore the `%xxx%` expression and just copy it into the 2nd bat file without executing anything.

Comment: Try doubling the percent characters, **`%`**, e.g. `(Echo  %%xxx%%)>>"2nd.bat"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment; to prevent the variables being expanded during the `Echo`, try doubling the percent characters, **`%`**:

```bat
(Echo %%xxx%%)>>"2nd.bat"
```

An example `1st.bat`:

```bat
@Echo Off
(@Echo Off
    Echo %%key%%
    Echo Echo %%random%%)>"2nd.bat"
```

Comment: IMO that should be `Echo  Echo %%key%%` otherwise 2nd.bat will try to execute whatever `%key%` contains at execution time.

Comment: @LotPings, it is an example; we have no idea if the content of the OP's variables are commands or a string, so presuming it in an example is not necessary. The `%%random%%` example could be changed to `Echo Echo %%random%%`, for the purposes of the answer though, so I've done so, _it may also help the OP to see the differences._

Comment: thanks, using %%xxx%% is working